# Zend Guard reporting Zend Optimizer not installed, but it is

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-optimizer

I'm testing Zend Guard 5 to encode PHP source code, and have encoded a working website.

When I view the site on my server, I get an error page saying "Zend Optimizer not installed" and that it requires Optimizer 3.0 or newer.

I'm sure I have Zend Optimizer installed. We're running Zend Platform on that server, which includes Zend Optimizer v3.3.7. According to phpinfo() and according to the Zend Platform status screen it's installed and working. Somehow Zend Guard doesn't agree.

Any idea why Guard encoded files don't seem to use the available Optimizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, after experimenting more it appears this error only happens on quite complex legacy websites. I suppose Guard is less flexible about bad coding than PHP itself is.

Simpler, more cleanly coded PHP encodes nicely and runs fine.